# Liferay: setting portlet preferences from portlet controller

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I want to ask you about one problem. I using Liferay 6.2. I have a custom portlet, which is embeded in my custom theme

```
$theme.runtime("mycustomportlet_WAR_mycustomportlet")
```

Here some settings from Liferay-portlet.xml

```
    <preferences-unique-per-layout>false</preferences-unique-per-layout>
    <preferences-owned-by-group>true</preferences-owned-by-group>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
```

In portlet controller render method I set portlet preferences (I want to make my portlet borderless)

```
    PortletPreferences preferences = renderRequest.getPreferences();        
    preferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders","false");
    try {
        preferences.store();
    } catch (ValidatorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I check Liferay and my custom embeded portlet borders there are. But PORTLETPREFERENCE table has a row with preferences below, with ID's according to liferay-portlet.xml setting:

```
<portlet-preferences>
<preference>
<name>portletSetupShowBorders</name>
<value>false</value>
</preference>
</portlet-preferences>
```

Can someone explain me where is mistake? Seem's like Liferay doesn't understand. I know how to set preferences another way. But I need this way to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `liferay-portlet.xml`:

```
<preferences-owned-by-group>true</preferences-owned-by-group>
```

The preferences for layout setup (including `portletSetupShowBorders`) is read from the layout, as long as it is not instanceable:

```
public PortletPreferences getStrictLayoutPortletSetup(Layout layout, String portletId) {

    long ownerId = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_ID_DEFAULT;
    int ownerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_LAYOUT;

    if (PortletConstants.hasUserId(portletId)) {
        ownerId = PortletConstants.getUserId(portletId);
        ownerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_USER;
    }

    ...
```

So as long as your preferences are stored per group, they are not taken into account....